# How to avoid race condition between Android Service and Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, race-condition

everyone.

I have written a service that downloads data and writes it to preference file periodically and an activity that reads data from preference file occasionally. So there is race condition. The service is permanent but the activity is not. How should I solve the race condition?

If I use Condition.await() and Condition.signalAll(), I must pass an object of Conditon from Service to Activity. Is this the best way? How can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [BroadcastReciever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Process some job on a service then send broadcast(after the job finished) to the activity.

Comment: For example, the service downloads and writes data on the beginning of every hour. The activity reads data on irregular time. We don't expect that the reading and writting occur at the same time.

Comment: For example, the service downloads and writes data on the beginning of every hour. The activity reads data on irregular time. We don't expect that the reading and writting occur at the same time. If use broadcast, activity receives the broadcast indicating that writting is finished at regular time. And where should I put the reading code? Is my understanding above right?